# ARP static entry after shutdown

Tags: networking, router, arp

I used New-NetNeighbor to set an ARP static entry but it's gone after the PC is shutdown. Is there a way to make it persistent even when shutdown ?

Thanks

Comment: It may be nit-picking, but I don't think it matters what the ARP table is when the machine is shut down; perhaps you want it to simply be restored on boot?

Comment: Actually I need it there when shutdown to wake on lan via the Internet. I need the ARP table to store the entry so the router can deliver the magic packet to my PC to wake it up.